# Fire ActivateRoute subscribe event when URL params changes

Tags: angular

Having this sub-component route :

```
export const ConsoRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'conso',
        component: ConsoComponent
    },
  {
    path: 'conso/:grain',
    component: ConsoComponent
  }
];
```

and

```
export class ConsoComponent implements OnInit {
....
    ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      var grain = params['grain'];
      ....
      reload some charts.  
    }
 }
```

chaning the current URL `http://localhost:5555/dashboard/USERNAME/conso`
with another username with :

```
this.$router.navigateByUrl(this.$router.url.replace(this.username, newUsername));
```

didn't fire the `this.route.params.subscribe`, how to force the subscribe event?

i also try [ApplicationRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ApplicationRef-class.html#!#tick-anchor)`.tick()`, the subscribe is not called also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.sub = this.route.url.subscribe(
      ....
    );
```